# SpyOn Service function call in constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am running into an issue of trying to spy on a service function call that gets called in the constructor. The test is basic, just verifying that the function call actually gets called.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [TestService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(service , "start").and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('start gets called', () => {

    expect(service .start).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

As for AppComponent , in the constructor it is simply calling service.start()
What I think the issue is that the spyOn gets called after the component is created but how would I spy on the service before injecting it? ie:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me the component's constructor has been called by the time you set up the spy, so need to change the sequence a bit.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  let service = TestBed.get(TestService);
  spyOn(service , "start").and.callThrough();
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Ref [Angular Test Bed](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/angular-test-bed/#_fixtures_and_di)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could've spyOn the service before the component was created.

Comment: Yes but what if I want to have a different return value in each test instead of always having the callThrough()

Comment: @RDNotorious you can use and.returnValue(x) instead of and.callThrough(), or you can use and.returnValues(x, y, z) to return values in order.  Also, there's no reason why you have to use the same beforeEach() for all tests if it's inconvenient